# Converging partial sequences in $B(0, 1)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm trying to solve the following exercise:

Let $M := B(0, 1)$ be the open unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$, prove or disprove that for every sequence $x_k$ in $M$, there exists a subsequence of $x_k$ that converges.

My initial thoughts were: if $M$ is compact, then the statement is true and as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $M$ is compact iff it is bounded and closed (by the Heine-Borel theorem). But $M$ is *not* closed so I can't use this argument which makes me suspect that the statement is actually false but I don't know how to show that.

Comment: Do you mean that every subsequence converges or that every sequence has a convergent subsequence? If you mean that every subsequence converges, this isn't even necessarily true for a compact set (since you're basically saying that every sequence converges).

Comment: @MarkSaving: You're right, that's a mistake, a convergent subsequence should exist, I will correct that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a slight subtlety here. Because the unit ball is bounded, it is a subset of a compact set. Hence, every sequence in the unit ball is also a sequence in this compact set, and thus has a convergent subsequence.

However, there need not be a convergent subsequence that converges to a value in the open ball. Consider the sequence $a_k = (1 - 2^{-k}, 0, ..., 0)$. The sequence converges to $(1, 0, ..., 0)$, and thus all its subsequences converge to $(1, 0, ..., 0)$. But this point is not in the open unit ball.

Comment: So there does not have to be a subsequence "convergent in $M$" correct? (I'm not completely sure if that means the same thing).

Comment: @Peter "convergent in $M$" means that the sequence converges to a point in $M$. So there does not have to be a subsequence convergent in $M$, as my example shows.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is trus because, since $B(0,1)\subset\overline{B(0,1)}$, which is compact. So, every sequence of elements of $B(0,1)$ is also a sequence of elements of $\overline{B(0,1)}$, and therefore it has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: My bad, it should have been "there exists a subsequence that converges" as per the comment by Mark Saving above.

Comment: I've edited my answer.